# On conjugacy classes of involution

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. If all the involution of $H$ lie in a conjugacy class of $G$, then what can we say about the structure of $H$?

Comment: That it is a group of even order?

Comment: This seems to be the same as asking about groups where the automorphism group acts transitively on the elements of order $2$ (by considering the holomorph of $H$).

Comment: Take $H$ to be any solvable group of even order, $p$ a prime not dividing $|H|$ and $G=H\times C_p$. $G$ and $H$ satisfy the conditions in question. We can *only* say that *$H$  is solvable group of even order*.

Comment: @pGroups We can't actually say that the order is even.

Comment: he is talking about involutions. (perhaps, you are considering groups without involutions too, is it?)

Comment: @pGroups Well, if there are no involutions, then they are all conjugate.

Comment: its ok! you are then right.